# Comment section on Github Pages

Tags: github

I have made a website that I published as Github Page. Since Github Pages is not a server provider and can only store a static website, I cannot use a comment section server side.

Is there any other way of implementing comments / discussion feature on github pages? For example feedback form can be handled using Google Forms.

Comment: either using a third party hosted comment system or using GitHub issues system as comment backbone. One solution that uses the later approach is  [utteranc](https://utteranc.es) (but there are many)

Comment: Please see the answers to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096243/adding-comments-in-blog-posts-on-github-pages

Comment: Unfortunately, that question doesn't exist anymore. And I came here with a similar query ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible anymore because as you said they only support static pages now. Yes, you can use google forums or something similar. You can also use GH discussions. You can find it on the [top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg5Ef.png) or go use a link. They are formated like this `github.com/<user/orgenisation name>/<repository name>/discussions`